# Unable to access list item inside a class

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I've been wrapping my head around this issue for the past 2 hours (keep in mind that I'm new to Flutter). I'm trying to check if I've set up everything properly for getting a movie list from OMDB. Everything seems okay except the fact that I don't know how to access something inside a list ie. originalTitle.

[image: (it detects result as a List from the model but it won't detect the strings inside)]

This is the model:

```
  class MovieItem {
  int page;
  int totalResults;
  int totalPages;
  List<Results> results;

  MovieItem({this.page, this.totalResults, this.totalPages, this.results});

  MovieItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    page = json['page'];
    totalResults = json['total_results'];
    totalPages = json['total_pages'];
    if (json['results'] != null) {
      results = new List<Results>();
      json['results'].forEach((v) {
        results.add(new Results.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['page'] = this.page;
    data['total_results'] = this.totalResults;
    data['total_pages'] = this.totalPages;
    if (this.results != null) {
      data['results'] = this.results.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Results {
  String posterPath;
  int id;
  String originalLanguage;
  String originalTitle;
  String title;

  Results(
      {this.posterPath,
      this.id,
      this.originalLanguage,
      this.originalTitle,
      this.title,});

  Results.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    posterPath = json['poster_path'];
    id = json['id'];
    originalLanguage = json['original_language'];
    originalTitle = json['original_title'];
    title = json['title'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['poster_path'] = this.posterPath;
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['original_language'] = this.originalLanguage;
    data['original_title'] = this.originalTitle;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should access the list item with square brackets.

Comment: can you add what you are getting in json['results'] ?

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to call a property on a `List<Result>` instead of `Result`.  The property you are attempting to access exists on `Result` ... if there is a `List` of `Result` objects, what do you expect to return with `movieItem.results.originalTitle`? There could be any number of `Result` object with possibly different titles?  If you just want to print them all out:

```
Future<MovieItem> movieItem() async {
   var movieItem = await
   client.movieItem();
   movieItem.results.forEach((result) => print(result.originalTitle));
   return movieItem;
}
```

The `forEach` will allow you to call the property and print it on every Result in the list

Answer (score 0):

Your movieItem model class has list of result objects. So when you call the client.movieItem method the you get a MovieItem Object, and it you want to print the specific result item then just do this

```
print(movieItem.results[0].originalTitle)
```

and if you want to access all the objects from the result list then using for loop you can achieve it

```
for(int i=0;i<movieItem.results.length;i++)
{
print(movieItem.results[i].originalTitle);
}
```